# Passing a pattern value from user to preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

Hello i have this code but there is a problem with preg_match on passing $pattern variable.

```
$pattern = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pregmatch']);
$pattern = "'".$pattern."'";
preg_match($pattern, $content, $m);
```

if i give this `/<span class=\"product_title\">(.*)<\/span>/`
in the $_POST['pregmatch'] pregmatch returns NULL.

If i change the code to this

```
//$pattern = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pregmatch']);
//$pattern = "'".$pattern."'";
preg_match('/<span class=\"product_title\">(.*)<\/span>/', $content, $m);
```

works like a charm.

So whats the deal here? Slashes creates this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What value holds the `content` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your additional lines appear to be causing a problem... if you were to do:

```
preg_match($_POST['pregmatch'], $content, $m);
```

You would probably get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

[`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) converts the angle brackets `<` and `>` from your input into the HTML escapes `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Thus your pattern becomes:

```
/&lt;span class=\"product_title"&gt;(.*)&lt;\/span&gt;/
```

Which won't match the `$content` if that's still raw HTML.

Also adding `'` around the pattern will screw it up:

```
 $pattern = "'".$pattern."'";
```

You then had two delimiters.

```
'/&lt;span class="product_title"&gt;(.*)&lt;\/span&gt;/'
```

Best idea is to use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) when unsure about variable state. And enable [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/error_reporting) whenever something doesn't work.